# How can I make a list of pointers in c#?

Tags: c#, pointers, monogame

I'm currently programming my own 2d engine with monogame and can't get any further because I want to create a list of sprite pointers. My idea is that every time a sprite is initialized it is added to the list and when the draw function is called, every sprite in the list is rendered with a foreach loop.
The problem is if I change the properties of the sprite, like position or color, then I have to refresh the list, and that's not the best way. My new idea is to make a list of pointers that point to the respective sprites.So that when you render you have access to the variable and not to a reference.Or maybe there is also a list object that does the work for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The need to separately update the list only applies to value types. If you made your sprite a value type, make it a reference type instead.

Comment: Paragraphs are free on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My idea is that every time a sprite is initialized it is added to the list and when the draw function is called, every sprite in the list is rendered with a foreach loop.

The need for having common objects that need to be updated and drawn along with the `Game` object is very frequent. You can have multiple approaches for implementing it. Monogame even has it's own implementation of it using the abstract class `GameComponents` and I have mentioned it in the end.

> The problem is if I change the properties of the sprite, like position or color, then I have to refresh the list, and that's not the best way.

I believe this problem is due to the fact that the objects in your list are value types and not reference types (equivalent to pointers in C#). In this case, you have the following approaches to try:

1. Instead of using the generic type `List<T>`, use a `LinkedList<T>` in `System.Collections.Generic`, and you should use it as follows:

```cs
class Game1:Game
{
    LinkedList<MyCustomClass> list;
    
    ...
    
    void LoadContent()
    {
        list = new LinkedList<MyCustomClass>();

        ...

        list.AddLast(myobject);
    }
    void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //Do not use a foreach loop. Instead, do this:
        for (var node = list.First; node != null; node = node.Next)
        {
            node.ValueRef.Update(); 
        //Important to use ValueRef, as it returns the reference of the object
        }

        ...


    }
}
```

Here, the `ValueRef` property of `LinkedListNode<T>` (Here returned by `list.First` property) will give you exactly what you need: A reference to your object.

2. Even if you use a List, it should be fine, but your Type must be a Reference type. This means instead of making your custom type as `struct`, you need to change it to `class`.

In case you are using method 2 given above, you might want to check out the `GameComponents` class, which is Monogame's in-built approach to this problem. `GameComponents` is an abstract class, so it goes without saying you need to change your type from `struct` to `class`.

Let's say you have your custom class as shown

```cs
public class MyCustomClass: Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent
{
    public MyCustomClass(Game game)
        : base(game)
    {

    }
}
```

The `LoadContent()`, `Initialize()`, and `Update()` methods are inherited and can be overridden to your liking.

You can create an instance of this class in your `Game` class, and add this object to the `Components` property of the `Game` object as shown

```cs
    var MyCustomObject = new MyCustomClass(this);
    Components.Add(MyCustomObject);
```

By doing this, The base class `Game` calls the `Update()`, `Draw()`, `LoadContent()` methods on its own respective calls.

You can iterate through your required objects using the following approach

```cs
    foreach (var item in Components)
    {
        if(item is MyCustomClass)
        {
            var myitem = item as MyCustomClass;
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @AntonMüller Please consider upvoting my answer if it helped.